# Finding the users location

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. I need to find the location of the user as soon as he/she logs in to the application. I do not want maps to be displayed, the location should be identified without the user's knowledge. Is it possible to do this using the Google maps API? or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
    protected LocationManager locationManager;  
        Context context;
        public String gps_loc;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 10, new MyLocationListener());
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            gps_loc = String.format("%1$s" +"-"+"%2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            Toast.makeText(Clockin.this, gps_loc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(class.this, "Provider status changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(class.this,"Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(class.this).create();
             alertDialog.setTitle("Activate GPS...");
             alertDialog.setButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);                   
                }
            });
             alertDialog.show();
             }      
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(class.this,"Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: remove the toast messages for getting o/p without the user's knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to use the `PASSIVE` location provider like so:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)yourActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location lastKnown = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
```

This returns the last known location received by the operating system, so this may be stale, but you can check when the location was retrieved, and by which provider by querying the location object.

In conclusion, the user will have no idea that you've gotten a location **except that your app will require the proper location permission(s).**